# How can I generate wiki docs with Epydoc?

Tags: ros, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the default API documentation generator (Doxygen), the code API docs for http://wiki.ros.org/ackermann_vehicle_gazebo are generated correctly. I want to use Epydoc instead of Doxygen, so I made the following changes:

- In ackermann_vehicle_gazebo/package.xml, I added a rosdoc element:

```
  <export>
    <architecture_independent/>
    <rosdoc config="rosdoc.yaml"/>
  </export>
```

- In ackermann_vehicle_gazebo, I created a rosdoc.yaml file:

```
- builder: epydoc
  config: epydoc.config
```

- In ackermann_vehicle_gazebo, I created an epydoc.config file:

```
[epydoc]
modules: nodes/*.py
docformat: restructuredtext
private: no
```

After making these changes, I received an e-mail from noreply@jenkins.ros.org with the subject "Build failed in Jenkins: doc-hydro-ackermann_vehicle #13". The mail contains a large number of messages, but I can't determine the error that caused them. What do I need to do in order to generate code API docs with Epydoc instead of Doxygen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100436/how-can-i-generate-wiki-docs-with-epydoc?/) by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on ROS Answers with karma: 792 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-11-12**:
It would help to post a link to the Jenkins doc job that failed. Can you run `rosdoc_lite` locally on your development system?

**Comment by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.ros.org/users/274/jim-rothrock/) on 2013-11-12**:
Link: http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-hydro-ackermann_vehicle/13/

Yes. If I do the following:

```
    cd catkin_ws/src/ackermann_vehicle/ackermann_vehicle_gazebo
    rosdoc_lite .
```

Documentation is written to ackermann_vehicle_gazebo/doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first problem is that `rosdoc_lite` ignores any output coming from `epydoc` which makes debugging / analyzing anything impossible. I have fixed this in: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/50

The second problem is that the `epydoc.config` file seems to be incorrect. When specifying the module file explicitly (rather then using wildcard matching) it started to generated html code. The patch for the `ackermann_vehicle_gazebo` package is here: https://github.com/wunderkammer-laboratory/ackermann_vehicle/pull/1

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1